# How to redefine \str_if_eq:xxTF for backward compatibility

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

I just updated all the packages for TeXLive 2012 today and it appears that `\str_if_eq:xxTF` has been deprecated.

How do I define a macro so that I can use the latest TeX Live but still be able to run the following with and older TeX Live 2011.  I find it incredibly useful when I run into problems to be able to run with an older release.

So with TeXLive2011 this correctly yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}

\def\SpecialDirName{special}%

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\GetFileName}{%
     O{default}%
     m%
     m% 
     m% 
    }{%
    \str_if_eq:xxTF{#1}{\SpecialDirName}{#4}{#2-#3-#4}%
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\edef\FileName{\GetFileName{a}{b}{c}}
FileName = "\FileName".

\edef\FileName{\GetFileName[special]{a}{b}{c}}
FileName = "\FileName".
\end{document}
```

Comment: See follow-up question for TeXLive 2020: [How to redefine \str_if_eq_x:nnTF for backward compatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/547159/4301).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest (complying with Joseph Wright's recommendation) not to use deprecated commands under any circumstance.

However, if you want just to test code, you can do in this way:

```
\cs_if_exist:NTF \str_if_eq_x:nnTF
 { \cs_gset_eq:NN \grill_str_if_eq_x:nnTF \str_if_eq_x:nnTF }
 { \cs_gset_eq:NN \grill_str_if_eq_x:nnTF \str_if_eq:xxTF }
```

and use in your code `\grill_str_if_eq_x:nnTF` which has the advantage of not polluting your code with a deprecated command that just appears once.

When you'll be outside the testing phase, it will be a breeze to change all occurrences of `\grill_str_if_eq_x:nnTF` with the "official" command.

Don't use deprecated functions in production code, please: in some cases not only the names are changed, but also the syntax or the way the functions work. For instance, sequences used to be indexed starting at zero, now they start at one and maintaining versions for the old style would be a nightmare.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, the new function is called `\str_if_eq_x:nnTF`, with a single `x`. Fixed.