# How to redefine \str_if_eq_x:nnTF for backward compatibility

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

In TeXLive 2012 `\str_if_eq:xxTF` was deprecated and replaced with `\str_if_eq_x:nnTF` (see *References* below).  Now it appears that with TeXLive 2020, `\str_if_eq_x:nnTF` has been deprecated.

The MWE below is an adpatation of the solution at the earlier question which allows one to work with TeXLive 2011 through TeXLive 2019 and has served me well. I have no plans to go back that far, but would like to revise the solution presented at the earler question:

```
\cs_if_exist:NTF \str_if_eq_x:nnTF
 { \cs_gset_eq:NN \grill_str_if_eq_x:nnTF \str_if_eq_x:nnTF }
 { \cs_gset_eq:NN \grill_str_if_eq_x:nnTF \str_if_eq:xxTF }
```

so that I can easliy switch between TeXLive 2019 and later.  The MWE below with TeXLive 2019 yields:

[image]

How do I make it work with *both* 2019 and 2020 such that the output is the same between both releases.

### References:

- [How to redefine \str_if_eq:xxTF for backward compatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109503/4301).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}

\def\SpecialDirName{special}%

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% Following is from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109503/4301.
%% Works fine in TeXLive 2019. I need it to work in 2019 and 2020.
\cs_if_exist:NTF \str_if_eq_x:nnTF
 { \cs_gset_eq:NN \grill_str_if_eq_x:nnTF \str_if_eq_x:nnTF }
 { \cs_gset_eq:NN \grill_str_if_eq_x:nnTF \str_if_eq:xxTF }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\GetFileName}{%
     O{default}%
     m%
     m% 
     m% 
    }{%
    \grill_str_if_eq_x:nnTF{#1}{\SpecialDirName}{#4}{#2-#3-#4}%
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\edef\FileName{\GetFileName{a}{b}{c}}
FileName = "\FileName".

\edef\FileName{\GetFileName[special]{a}{b}{c}}
FileName = "\FileName".
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does https://gist.github.com/moewew/004086466413b226d2c4e18d18b0303f work? The new recommended version for expanded string comparison is `\str_if_eq:eeTF`. If you only ever compare with `\SpecialDirName` and `\SpecialDirName` is always defined to expand to a string with a simple `\def`, then `\str_if_eq:noTF` might also work (I'm not sure, but suspect that version has been available for a long time).

Comment: I should add that the `no` version also assumes that its first argument `#1` in the example is a string and not only something that expands to a string eventually. So the `no` version is only good if you have good control over both inputs.

Comment: @moewe: Doesn't seem to work. Fails with both 2019 and 2020 with the error is "Undefined control sequence.
\GetFileName code ...3#4->\grill_str_if_eq_x:nnTF"

Comment: I renamed your macro from `\grill_str_if_eq_x:nnTF` to `\grill_str_if_eq:eeTF` for consistency with the new macro name. Did you take that into account? (I should have probably posted a fully working document from the start. Updated. I tested the MWE on a fully updated MikTeX that should be equivalent to a fully updated TeX live 2020 for all intents and purposes here.)

Comment: @moewe: Opps, misse that change. Yep, seems to work fine with the givne MWE.

Comment: @PeterGrill I'm probably in no position of doing saying, but it's my duty, so: “don't do that” :-). Duties apart, if you want all four conditional variants you can use `\prg_set_eq_conditional:NNn \str_if_eq_x:nn \str_if_eq:ee { TF , T , F , p }`, then make variants with `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_eq_x:nn { Vn, etc... } { TF , T , F , p }`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Please elaborate on what you are suggesting I not do? I need to be able to switch between TeXLive 2020 and 2019 for a while, so if there is a better way, please let me know.  I am just trying to adapt a solution from an earlier question so I can traistion to TeXLive2020. The prior solution has worked for many year so seemt that the minimal changes suggested by moewe seems like a good idea to me. Also should metnion, I don't know expl3 very well (barely eniough to hack things togetherr).

Comment: @PeterGrill No, there's really no good way out, sorry. What I meant is that it's not good practice, so from an official position I must say “don't do that”, but I do that myself quite a lot :-) The solution is the test moewe suggested (reading it now, my comment was a bit confusing, sorry about that). Also it's better to make `\str_if_eq:ee` a copy of `\str_if_eq_x:nn` on older systems, rather than make (as I did in my comment above) `\str_if_eq_x:nn` a copy of `\str_if_eq:ee` on newer systems, so its easier when you want to drop support of older versions.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: OK, thanks for the clarrificaiton. That makes sense.